# Json multiple string arrays into multiple Java String list

Tags: java, json

I am looking for solution to convert my json that contains multiple fields with string arrays and that i need to convert into Java list of string. I am using Jackson to do that.
and below is the request object

```
public class PullQuestionRequest {
private List<String> classNo;
private List<String> subject;
private List<String> topic;
private List<String> learningElement;
private List<String> complexity;
//and setters and getters for the fields..
```

and below is my json

```
{
"classNo": ["7","10"],
"subject": ["Maths","English"],
"topic": ["PS","NS"],
"learningElement": ["PS","ZOOLOGY"],
"complexity" : ["LEVEL 1","LEVEL 2"]
}
```

below is the code for my controller.

```
  public GetAllQuestionResponse pullQuestions(@RequestParam("data") String questionRequest)
        throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
    PullQuestionRequest request = Obj.readValue(questionRequest, PullQuestionRequest.class);
```

I could be able to convert whole json into java object. I need a help How to pull the string arrays for ClassNo , subject and others as List of strings in java.

Comment: you''ll need setters for classNo etc.

Comment: I have added setter sand getters for all these fields.

Comment: and the problem is? Do you get errors running your code, or null values, or....

Comment: Hi Marc, i am looking for solution how to proceed furhter to map those classNo and topic etc into java list<strings> ..

Comment: Jackson should map arrays to List by default, so write a test or start debugging and post the results